# Why is Jetty Http Client so slow?

Tags: java, jetty

I have a jetty Http client configured as follows:

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.setTimeout(connectionTimeout);
    client.setIdleTimeout(readTimeout);
    client.setMaxConnectionsPerAddress(100);
    client.setThreadPool(new QueuedThreadPool(100));
    client.setConnectorType(HttpClient.CONNECTOR_SELECT_CHANNEL);
    client.setMaxRetries(retries);
```

and the call below always takes ~400ms which seems way to long for an async call. To clarify I am not worried about the response time of the request. Just the method call keeps my thread busy for 400ms. It seems this method is blocking somewhere but it should be async.

```
    client.send(httpExchange);
```

Am I messing up my configuration some how?

Comment: Have you tried this with a variety of servers?

Comment: No but this should be an async call call so the server should not matter.

Comment: How are you measuring the duration of the `send()` call?

Comment: Sys out currentTimeMills before and after.

Comment: What Jetty version? (You should include version numbers of all relevant software in your question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't had time to test this, but I suspect your fix is

```
client.setConnectBlocking(false);
```

It would appear, that by default, an HttpClient blocks on connect - even if the connector is non-blocking for the send/receive of the request+response.

*(That assumes Jetty 7. I haven't checked for Jetty 8)*

Comment: Thank you! Fixed an issue I was seeing with Jetty 8.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why the call to `send()` might be taking that long, but if it's too slow for you then it's a simple matter to offload the `send()` call to another thread:

```
public class SendThread extends Thread {
    private HttpClient client;
    private HttpExchange exchange;

    public SendThread(HttpClient client, HttpExchange exchange) {
        this.client = client;
        this.exchange = exchange;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        client.send(exchange);
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
new SendThread(client, exchange).start();
```

...in place of:

```
client.send(httpExchange);
```

If you want to try and figure out why the library is taking so long, you can also try looking through the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client/7.0.2.v20100331/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpClient.java#HttpClient.send%28org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange%29).  At a quick glance I would say that 1) what `send()` does is not exactly trivial, and 2) the only thing that appears to be asynchronous is the sending of the actual data/payload to the server; things such as creating the initial connection to the server seem to be done synchronously as part of the call to `send()`.